# Service for Processing Credit Card Information on Mobile Application that is PCI Compliant

Tags: android, ios, mobile, pci-compliance

I'm currently working on a mobile application (for both iOS and Android) that needs some sort of service that holds the credit card data for me so it can be PCI compliant. I've looked into a lot of different services, but nothing quite does what I need and I don't have the resources to build something that is PCI compliant from scratch.

Basically, there will be two types of users; for the purpose of this post, we'll refer to them as buyers and sellers. The sellers will have stored bank account information so the money can be deposited. The buyers will have credit card information. Buyers will not be linked to sellers and they will be able to pick WHO to pay. Is there a service that will allow a capability like this? I've looked at Spreedly, Braintree, and Stripe but haven't convinced myself it has this capability.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please go through Paypal Adaptive payments. You can use Paypal Adaptive Payments API without getting PCI. Also, you can split payments using this.

Comment: PayPal Adaptive Payments states: "Important: Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product. It is restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal." I don't believe it will be easy to be able to use this. Any advice?

Comment: Recently, in one of my app. I have used that and got approval from Paypal. I think you need to check out the whole adaptive payments documentation once if it meets your requirements. 

In my case when buyer was paying for an item, payments were divided in two parts: seller and app owner. 
For this I used adaptive payments. 
And in other case for transferring amount to bank account, we are manually adding the amount. Also, there are payouts in paypal. Please go though that once in mode detail.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is rapidly going to become a legal advice question which cannot receive a useful answer here. While services like Stripe or Braintree or Paypal make many of the mechanics of payment processing easier that doesn't resolve some significant policy questions you need to address. For example determining if card issuers allow charges for the type of business you intend to operate. Additionally, by mediating between buyers and sellers you may need to comply with OFAC, anti-money laundering, consumer protection and other banking regulations.

Comment: Great thanks for the help! I'll look into this issue some more.